# Firebase Phone Auth through backend server nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to add firebase phone authentication from server side using nodejs?

Frontend with React redux toolkit. (Don't want to include firebase in frontend just for authentication only, extra overload)

If it can't be done, what is the best way to implement phone auth through backend?

Frontend: react redux tool kit,
Backend: nodejs, express, firebase auth

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through `Firebase Auth REST API`. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318300/firebase-rest-api-authenticate-with-phone-number?rq=1) for a detailed answer.