# Laravel 9 Project with Firebase Phone Number Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication, laravel-9

Is it possible to connect firebase phone number authentication with laravel 9 project. I have been searching this for a while and found most of the answers using javascript.In the 'firebase-php', there is no such function  for phone authentication.

Please notify me if you know how to connnect firebase phone authentication with laravel 9 php directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Laravel project still delivers HTML and JavaScript to the client, I'd recommend first trying to integrate with the regular JavaScript SDK for Firebase, documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

If you want to sign in from the server in your PHP code, there is no official SDK from Firebase for using it within PHP. So your best options are to use the REST API (which seems to allow what you want to do) or to look for a 3rd party library (which typically wrap the REST API).

Also see:

- [Firebase REST API Authenticate With Phone Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318300/firebase-rest-api-authenticate-with-phone-number)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to use the javascript sdk .